# Even if I use reversed range, still 'list index out of range in Python' happen

Tags: python, list, indexing

I found when I use 'pop' in for loop, it can make error like 'list index out of range in Python'. Cause removing one index makes list short.

And also found that if I use kind of reversed range, I can fix this error.
But while I'm trying to apply this what I've learnt on Stack Overflow, I still couldn't solve this problem.

for example

```
candidates = []
def make_candidates(user_group, ban_group):
    for i in range(len(user_group)-1, -1, -1):   
        for j in range(len(ban_group)):
            if len(user_group[i]) == len(ban_group[j]):
                candidates.append(user_group.pop(i))

    return candidates

print(make_candidates(["frodo", "fradi", "crodo", "abc123", "frodoc"], ["*rodo", "*rodo", "******"]))
```

range is (4, -1, -1), so 'i' is 4 to 0.

when 'i=4, j=2', len(user_gorup[4]) == len(ban_group[2])) -> candidates = ["frodoc"] -> user_group = ["frodo", "fradi", "crodo", "abc123"]

when 'i=3, j=2', len(user_group[3]) == len(ban_group[2])) -> candidates = ["frodoc", "abc123"] -> user_group = ["frodo", "fradi", "crodo"]

In this way, there's no out of list index. When range got short, list also got short, so there's no problem. Isn't it? Why there still error happen?

Comment: What is this algorithm trying to do? Return a set of ban candidates?

Comment: What is the actual calculation you are trying to perform? Do you actually *need* for the `user_group` to change? What should the `candidates` be afterward?

Comment: Never use indices of a list you're destroying as you're looping through it. Replace the first `for` loop by a `while` loop: `while user_group:` then `user = user_group.pop()` and use `user` wherever you have `user_group[i]` or `user_group.pop()`

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic to `range`. It does not interact with the `for` statement - it only provides a sequence of numeric values to use.

In the outer loop, `for i in range(len(user_group)-1, -1, -1):`, the `range` object is created *once, ahead of time* before any looping happens. The first time through, we use an index `i == 4`, then `i == 3` and so on.

Your expectation is that even if the list is shortened, `i` will still be a valid index for the list. But this is clearly not actually the case. Look closely - there are `j` many opportunities to remove an item in the inner loop, so the list could be `.pop`ped *more than once* before `i` decreases.

But even then - supposing that only one item is removed - *is `i` now actually the index you want*? Logic like this is very tricky and there is no reason to do anything this tricky. There is no reason to use indexing at all - you should refer directly to the list elements, and you should not try to remove anything until you are done.

Compute the `candidates` first, and then *if you need to*, you can compute a *separate* list of the non-candidate users.

I will simplify the code by giving names to the key steps using functions, and then by using list comprehensions instead of loops to do the processing - this saves you from having to think in terms of `.append` and procedural logic, and lets you just describe the list you want.

```
def should_ban(user, ban_group):
    # I don't understand the reason for comparing name lengths, but
    # this should do the same as your original code tried to do:
    return any(len(user) == len(ban) for ban in ban_group)

def ban_candidates(user_group, ban_group):
    return [user for user in user_group if should_ban(user, ban_group)]

# Then we can filter the bans out of the user group:
def unbanned(user_group, banned):
    return [user for user in user_group if user not in banned]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. The problem was caused by 'j'. That logic was wrong and pointless. It was made while I was trying to make some valid logic. I knew it is wrong way but wondered why it makes error. I had to make another logic though, anyway I learned important feature of range thanks to you. Have a good one.